# How to share a data on facebook through phonegap app

Tags: android, facebook, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am make an Android (Native app) with help of(JQuery Mobile and Phonegap) in which i want to share the data on facebook please help me out how i will do these

IN HTML5:-

```
<div data-role="content">
       <label for="textarea">Textarea:</label>
       <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
    <a href="#page1" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Share</a>
</div>
```

in this app i want to share the data which is there in textarea should display on facebook when i click button

without using any plugin if we can do please help me out or with plugin we have to do then tell me how i can do step by step process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Share data on Facebook through PhoneGap

> Use Child browser OR InAppbrowser plugin then add follwing code

```
function FBConnect()
{
if(window.plugins.childBrowser == null)
{
    ChildBrowser.install();
}
}

$("#share_on_wall").live("click", function(event){
   if(event.handled !== true){

     var fb = FBConnect.install();          
     fb.postFBWall(desc, post_url, vPromotionPicture_url, vTitle);

     event.handled = true;
   }
   return false;
});



FBConnect.prototype.postFBWall = function(message, urlPost, urlPicture, vTitle)
{
    if(urlPicture == undefined)
       urlPicture = "";
      urlPost ="";

     var url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=your_app_id&link="+encodeURIComponent(urlPost)+"&picture="+encodeURIComponent(urlPicture)+"&name="+encodeURIComponent(vTitle)+"&caption=&description="+encodeURIComponent(message)+"&redirect_uri=your_redirect_uri";
      var ref = window.open(url, 'random_string', 'location=no');

      ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {

       });
      ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
       console.log(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
       var post_id = event.url.split("post_id=")[1];
       var cancel_url = event.url.split("#")[0];
       if(post_id != undefined){
            setTimeout(function() {                   

                ref.close();

            }, 5000);
     }
     if(cancel_url != undefined && cancel_url == your_redirect_uri){
            setTimeout(function() {
                ref.close();                        
            }, 1000);
     }                         
  });
  ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {

  });
 }
```

Comment: 1)First of all you should use ChildBrowser plugin for android Or InAppBrowser Plugin add in your project2) You should get client id from facebook developer site 3) Then use connectShare function with parameter, it return access token then pass it to shareOnFaceBook(access_token) call postFBWall function inside shareOnFaceBook with parameter.Thats Work...!

Comment: postFBGraph function does not exist.